# Change color of 'less than' and 'greater than' from around tags in HTML with intellij without affecting vue templates

Tags: intellij-idea, vue.js

we are looking at a lot of HTML usually.

Now, `<`, `>` and `</` around the tags are splattered everywhere. But unless there is a syntax error, those really have no value. And syntax errors are highlighted.

So instead of looking at:

[image]

I would prefer to look at, note you can change this in

`Settings -> Editor -> Color scheme -> HTML -> HTML Code`

[image]

the problem is if I change it this way, the vue templates get affected as well and all condition operators become gray too like the `<>`

`mycomponent.vue`

[image]

notice `all` and `in`

is there a different way to do it?

Comment: these constructions are colored according to `HTML Code` color preferences; there is no way to alter this, sorry. If you think that they should use different color settings, please create a feature request in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case of using [language injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html)

If you don't have [explicit vue.js support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/vue-js.html) already set up (or if it doesn't handle it), you can define language injections to highlight that area as javascript expressions.

https://studgeek.com/2010/08/16/intellijidea-webstorm-knockout-data-bind-attributes/

Shows how a dummy javascript context can be set up for arbitrary xml attributes.

[image]

In this (quite dated) image, you can see the Prefix is set to a random window variable object, and the suffix ends the object, this simply wraps the code in the xml attribute with something roughly resembling the correct context for the javascript.

The `data-bind` xml attribute in this case, would be swapped out for `v-if` `v-else` or any other vue attributes that take a binding that looks similar to javascript.

If this fails to work, it sounds like an IntelliJ bug which should be reported.

Comment: Is it capable to active/enable the language injection automatically?

Comment: I don't understand the question. After you set this up once, it should detect the properties and change the language error detection / highlighting appropriately.

Comment: that's a neat solution. What I realized... I think the issue was related that I did not define a different color to javascript variables... damn. So vue js plugin active, then change color of javascript variables. I'll still accept this answer as it will certainly come handy.

Comment: I also wasn't sure about XML tag characters appearing inside attribute values

Answer (score 1):

You can try if [rainbow brackets plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets) works for you.

It changes the color of brackets and gives each pair of opening and closing bracket a unique colour to make it easier to identify which belongs together.

Comment: even though I somehow like the idea, I want to give brackets and `<` etc _less_ value. Having rainbow colored brackets etc will give them more value. Some I _do_ want to have clear. For example, as I am using php the array `[]` indicators are important

Comment: I understand, then this plugin is not for you as it doesn't provide the option to control the colours that way.